# Hibernate bidirectional many to one mapping, can't get parent object from child

Tags: java, hibernate

I have some questions while using Hibernate 4. I have a self mapping POJO which is bidirectional too. I can get the children category list from parent category, but I can't get parent category from its child. 
**Here is my code:**

```
@Entity
public class Category {

private Long id;
private String cateName;
private String cateType;
private String description;
private List<Category> childCategories;
private Category category;

public Category() {
    childCategories = new ArrayList<Category>();
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
public Category getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(Category category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public String getCateName() {
    return cateName;
}
public void setCateName(String cateName) {
    this.cateName = cateName;
}
public String getCateType() {
    return cateType;
}
public void setCateType(String cateType) {
    this.cateType = cateType;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
public List<Category> getChildCategories() {
    return childCategories;
}

public void setChildCategories(List<Category> childCategories) {
    this.childCategories = childCategories;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Category [id=" + id + ", cateName=" + cateName + ", cateType="
            + cateType + ", description=" + description + "]" + "Parent: " + category;
}

}
```

It's a normal nested category mapping. I can use `category.getChildCategories()` to get children list normally, but if I use `category.getCategory()`, it returns the parent object only contains id, and others are null, like this: `[id=7, cateName='Java', cateType='2', description='java category', category=[id='2', cateName=null, cateType=null, description=null, category= null]]`. How to fetch all the parent object until root? Really need your help, thank you!
Additional:
The `category` is retrieved in this way:
1. Create transient object `category`
2. Use `saveOrUpdate()` method to persist it.
3. Use `getIdentifier()` to return the Id of added category.
4. Use `get()` to retrieve this category object immediately.
So I thought if hibernate returned a cached persistent object if I retrieve the object immediately it was persisted?

Comment: Did you have a look at the generated queries?

Comment: It's weird, there was no queries generated. :(

Comment: Check whether the show_sql flag is set to true. Ideally there should be atleast the mapping information shown in the logs. Also, after you did saveOrUpdate() do you have a flush before getting the identifier?

Comment: Ah,thank you askappy, I use evict and solved the problem!  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After calling `saveOrUpdate()` method, make sure to call `evict()` after getting identifier.

> **void org.hibernate.Session.evict(Object object)**
>   Remove this instance from the session cache. Changes to the instance
>   will not be synchronized with the database. This operation cascades to
>   associated instances if the association is mapped with
>   cascade="evict".